# Filter a list by another list C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following business objects:

```
    public class ItemCategoryBO
    {
       public string ItemCategory { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemBO
    {
       public int ItemId { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string ItemCategory { get; set; } 
    }

    List<ItemCategoryBO> categoryList = new List<ItemCategoryBO>();

    ItemCategoryBO itemCategory = new ItemCategoryBO();
    itemCategory.ItemCategoryCd = "CARS";
    itemCategory.Title = "Cars";

    ItemCategoryBO itemCategory2 = new ItemCategoryBO();
    itemCategory.ItemCategoryCd = "PLANES";
    itemCategory.Title = "Planes";

    categoryList.Add(itemCategory);
    categoryList.Add(itemCategory2);

    List<ItemBO> itemList = new List<ItemBO>();

    ItemBO item1 = new ItemBO();
    item1.ItemId = 1;
    item1.Title = "1st item";
    item1.ItemCategoryCd = "OTHER";

    ItemBO item2 = new ItemBO();
    item2.ItemId = 2;
    item2.Title = "2nd Item";
    item2.ItemCategoryCd = "CARS";

    ItemBO item3 = new ItemBO();
    item3.ItemId = 3;
    item3.Title = "3rd Item";
    item3.ItemCategoryCd = "PLANES";

    itemList.Add(item1);
    itemList.Add(item2);
    itemList.Add(item3);
```

If I have a list of a few categories, how could I find a list of items that contain a category in the list of categories? (In my example, I want to get back items 2 and 3)

Comment: What are your lists? And to be sure, what does 'filter by' mean here?

Comment: I truly don't understand the down votes here. It isn't very hard to figure out what the OP is asking for. And if you really thing it is bad enough to warrant a down vote, leave the OP some feedback to explain why you down voted them.

Comment: @CharlieKilian really don't understand? after commenting `It isn't very hard to figure out what the OP is asking for`?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detail, I have updated my question :) Thanks.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you have a situation like:

```
List<ItemBO> items;
List<ItemCategoryBO> categories;
```

and you wish to get all the items that have a category that is in your list of categories, you can use this:

```
IEnumerable<ItemBO> result = items.Where(item =>
    categories.Any(category => category.ItemCategory.equals(item.ItemCategory)));
```

The `Any()` operator enumerates the source sequence and returns true as soon as an item satisfies the test given by the predicate. In this case, it returns true if the categories list contains an ItemCategoryBO where its ItemCategory string is the same as the item's ItemCategory string.
More information about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx#standardqueryops_topic15)

Comment: Thank you so much Diana, still a little new to linq. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Potential revision to this code:

`List<ItemBO> result = items.Where(item =>
    categories.Any(category => category.ItemCategory.equals(item.ItemCategory))).ToList();`

As written currently you will get an error as it returns an IEnumerable instead of a List<T>

Comment: Excellent. but return will be  IEnumerable<ItemBO>

Comment: 2 days I was fighting a battle to do what I could in SQL in LINQ, and I could finally do it with this. Such an 'AHA' moment

Answer (score 1):

Try using some linq

```
  List<ItemBO> itm = new List<ItemBO>;
 //Fill itm with data

 //get selected item from control

 string selectedcategory = cboCatetories.SelectedItem;

 var itms = from BO in itm where itm.ItemCategory = selectedcategory                              select itm;

itms now contains all items in that category
```

Comment: Thanks Micah, I updated my question, I'm looking for a way to dynamically filter based on another list, not just one item's category

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<ItemBO> items = ...;
ItemCategoryBO category = ...;

List<ItemBO> filteredItems = items
    .Where( i => i.ItemCategory.Equals(category) )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Updated to address OP's updated question:**

If I have a list of a few categories, how could I find a list of items that contain a category in the list of categories? (In my example, I want to get back items 2 and 3)

I think you actually should do this in two steps. First, get your distinct list of items. Then, from your items, get your list of categories. So:

```
// First, get the distinct list of items
List<ItemBO> items = new List<ItemBO>();
foreach ( var category in categories )
{
    foreach ( var item in category.Items )
    {
        if ( !items.Contains(item) )
            items.Add(item);
    }
}

// Second, get the list of items that have the category.
List<ItemBO> filteredItems = items
    .Where( i => i.ItemCategory.Equals(category) )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: How can I do this for a list of categories?

Comment: @CharlieKilian i will cancel my downvote ASAP i understand what your answer answers

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I did in [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net)

```
void Main()
{

    var cat1 = new ItemCategoryBO {ItemCategory="c1", Title = "c1"};
    var cat2 = new ItemCategoryBO {ItemCategory="c2", Title = "c2"};

    var item1 = new ItemBO { ItemId = 1, Title = "item1", ItemCategory="c1"};
    var item2 = new ItemBO { ItemId = 1, Title = "item2", ItemCategory="c2"};
    var item3 = new ItemBO { ItemId = 1, Title = "item3", ItemCategory="c2"};
    var item4 = new ItemBO { ItemId = 1, Title = "item4", ItemCategory="c3"};

    var items = new List() {item1, item2, item3, item4};
    var categories = new List() {cat1, cat2};

    var itemsInCategory = from item in items 
    join category in categories on  item.ItemCategory equals category.ItemCategory into itemInCategory
    from categoryItem in itemInCategory
    select new {item.Title, item.ItemCategory};

    itemsInCategory.Dump(); 
}

// Define other methods and classes here
      public class ItemCategoryBO
        {
           public string ItemCategory { get; set; }
           public string Title { get; set; }
        }

        public class ItemBO
        {
           public int ItemId { get; set; }
           public string Title { get; set; }
           public string ItemCategory { get; set; } 
        }
```

This returns:

```
Title, ItemCategory
item1 c1 
item2 c2 
item3 c2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
var result = (Object to search in).Where(m => (Object to compare to).Any(r => r.Equals(m.Key)).ToList();
```