# .net 5 MVC, Using a filtered list to filter the second list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I will list what I have in my code first.

WorkOrderModel

```
public class WorkOrderModel
{
    public int RowID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Type { get; set; } 
    [Key]
    public string Base_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Lot_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Split_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Sub_ID { get; set; }

    #nullable enable
    public string? Part_ID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Close_Date { get; set; }
    public char Status { get; set; }
}

public class OperationModel
{
    [Key]
    public short Sequence_No { get; set; }
    public string Resource_Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(7, 2)")]
    public decimal Run_Hrs { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(7, 2)")]
    public decimal Act_Run_Hrs { get; set; }
    public string Operation_Type { get; set; }
    public char Status { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Close_Date { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string WorkOrder_Type { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string WorkOrder_Base_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string WorkOrder_Lot_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string WorkOrder_Split_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string WorkOrder_Sub_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then `WOListViewModel` for combining two above(and more but they are not in use yet)

```
public class WoListViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<WorkOrderModel> WorkOrders { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<OperationModel> Operations { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<PartModel> Parts { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<LaborTicketModel> LaborTickets { get; set; }
}
```

and my WorkOrderController

```
public IActionResult Index(string woSearch = null, string tcSearch = null, string tdSearch = null)
{
        WoListViewModel woListViewModel = new()
        {
            WorkOrders = _dbContext.Work_Order.Where(w => w.Sub_ID != "0")
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdSearch))
        {
            woListViewModel.Operations = _dbContext.Operation.Where(o => o.Resource_Id == tdSearch);

            woListViewModel.WorkOrders = woListViewModel.WorkOrders.Where(w => (w.Base_ID + "-" + w.Sub_ID + "/" + w.Lot_ID) ==
                                            (from o in woListViewModel.Operations
                                             select  (o.WorkOrder_Base_ID + "-" + o.WorkOrder_Sub_ID + "/" + o.WorkOrder_Lot_ID)).ToQueryString()
                                             );
        }
}
```

What I am trying to do in `IActionResult` under `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdSearch))`is that filter `woListViewModel.Operations` by `tdSearch`.
Then use the result to filter `woListViewModel.WorkOrders`.
Both models have Base_ID, Sub_ID, Lot_ID as common in SQL server(though column names are not exact, they are matching data) and if I was going to do this two-stage filtering in Excel, I could merge two tables in PowerQuery first then filter.

While I have no idea if I am doing this right somehow I was able to write a controller code without an error in Visual Studio, but when it was run produced the error below.

```
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<OperationModel>()
.Where(o => o.Resource_Id == __tdSearch_0)
.Select(o => o.WorkOrder_Base_ID + "-" + o.WorkOrder_Sub_ID + "/" + o.WorkOrder_Lot_ID)
.ToQueryString()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
```

As its suggestion I changed `.ToQueryString()` to others listed but no success.

Please help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Filter a list by another list C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745900/filter-a-list-by-another-list-c-sharp/10746091)
Found the answer from the link above then changed my code as below.

```
woListViewModel.WorkOrders = woListViewModel.WorkOrders
                             .Where(w => woListViewModel.Operations
                                   .Any(o => (o.WorkOrder_Base_ID + "." + o.WorkOrder_Sub_ID + "." + o.WorkOrder_Lot_ID)
                                       .Equals(w.Base_ID + "." + w.Sub_ID + "." + w.Lot_ID)));
```