# Querying data from Table and passing to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Need help with this coding.
Here I want to get request details from the main request table which is called **"AppRequest"**. Here I have queried some requests and need to load the main details of the request from the AppRequest table. In the **"ListRequesDropDown"** is getting the main request ids from the AppRequest. So I want to pass that request-id data to the view. Currently **"return View(db.AppRequest.ToList());"** will shows the all the requests.

```
 public class PendingRequestMController : Controller
    {
        private zSqlDb db = new zSqlDb();
        // GET: PendingRequests to manager view
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           //Checking User ID
            var UsrID = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserId").FirstOrDefault();
            string UsrIDT = UsrID.Value;
       // Checking is there any pending request to the above user ID
            List <int> PendingRequestsforAprv = db.ApproveParties.ToList().Where(r => r.Approver_Id == int.Parse(UsrIDT ) && r.Approve_Status==false).ToList().
            Select(x => x.ApprovalProcess_Id).ToList();

            List<int> ReqTypeDropDown = db.ApprovalProcess.Where(r => PendingRequestsforAprv.Contains( r.Id )).Select(x => x.Req_Id).ToList();

            return View(db.AppRequest.ToList());
  
        }
    }
```

Comment: "return View(db.AppRequest.ToList());" will shows the all the requests"? Yes it does, you do not filter anything? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @VDWWD I'm filtering some requests that are directed to the userids. Here `List<int> ReqTypeDropDown` it gets the request Id nos. So I want to pass that related request-id details to the view.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745900/filter-a-list-by-another-list-c-sharp/10746091

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you, This is the one I wanted. Tried and it worked